# What is the output of an iPhone headphone jack?

Tags: headphones

When I plug my speakers into a headphone jack on my iPhone, is the output stereo or mono?

Answer (score 6):

The iPhone headphone jacks [are 1/8" (3.5mm) stereo jacks.](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html)  If you have a stereo cable plugged in, the output will be stereo.

Comment: Interesting side-note, the external speakers on the iPhone are 'mono', and I believe only output the left channel..

Comment: @ntt On my iPhone, of the two holes on the bottom, the one on the right (if the screen is facing you) is a mono speaker and the one on the left is phone's primary microphone.

Comment: Indeed.. But it takes the left channel of the audio to send to that mono speaker..